# Table schema conversion between 2 different databases

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql conversion work.I had asked about it few days before . I am explaining my requirements here properly.

I have 2 databases called onedb and twodb. In both databases I have a table called data. In twodb the table data contains 4 fields called a,b,c, and d . Also in onedb the table data contains 7 fields called b,a,d,c,e,f,g. The  4 fields a,b,c,d are there in both the tables.

Now I need to insert all the values in twodb table data into the onedb table data without effecting the structure of onedb table data.

Also there are around some 100 rows in table data of twodb and there is currently no rows in table data of onedb

How can I achieve this,Is there a simple query to achieve it or should i write some sort of php code to acheive it.

Please Help
Thank YOu

Comment: To convert onebd to towdb's schema, doesn't that mean REMOVING fields e, f & g?  And why would the number of records have any bearing on how to alter a table's schema?

Comment: Could you perhaps list a sequence of actions that would accomplish what you want, just to make clear what that is?  Don't worry about if they are legal DB operations or not.

Comment: @ScottHunter Hunter I need to insert all the values in twodb table data into the onedb table data without effecting the structure of onedb table data

Answer (score 1):

To alter the schema of a table, you can use the ALTER TABLE command.

Comment: If it is to remove e,f and g ,then i just have to export the content from other table right?

Answer (score 0):

Import the table data from onedb into twodb, but rename it to onedata.  (you may need to edit the SQL file you are importing)

use alter table to add new fields to onedata  - copied from schema for twodb

then you need to update the onedata table from data, hopefully you have a key.

here is a prototype statement.  It may need much tweaking

```
UPDATE data, onedata
 SET data.e=onedata.e, data.f=onedata.f, data.g=onedata.g
 WHERE onedata.mainkey= data.mainkey
```

That's assuming that you can match the tables by that key.

Comment: I just reread the question.  Evidently, the onedata table is empty.  All you have to do is alter the schema for data in  twodb  by ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN ... (look it up in the manual)

Comment: I need to insert all the values in twodb table data into the onedb table data without effecting the structure of onedb table data

Comment: insert into onedb.data(a,b,c,d) SELECT a,b,c,d FROM twodb.data;

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into onedb.data (a, b, c, d)
select b, a, d, c
from twodb.data;
```

Oops, I did not see that this answer was already given.

Comment: you can always delete your post if you don't want it anymore